# Extracting substring

Tags: android, string, substring

i have some problems extracting strings

i am making a multiple choice with 4 choices (e.g. as buttons), with the choices by referencing to the filename. The file (i.e. the question) is a png and the filename is Number-Q01AZ7BZ8CZ9DZ10ANZ8.png. These png are put under assets folder.

```
     Set<String> regions = regionsMap.keySet(); // get Set of regions

     // loop through each region
     for (String region : regions) 
     {
        if (regionsMap.get(region)) // if region is enabled
        {
           // get a list of all flag image files in this region
           String[] paths = assets.list(region);

           for (String path : paths) 
              fileNameList.add(path.replace(".png", ""));
        } // end if
     } // end for

String fileName = fileNameList.get(randomIndex);

if (!quizCountriesList.contains(fileName)) 
{
   quizCountriesList.add(fileName); // add the file to the list

   String nextImageName = quizCountriesList.remove(0);
   correctAnswer = nextImageName; // update the correct answer

   int AZ = correctAnswer.indexOf("AZ");
   int BZ = correctAnswer.indexOf("BZ");
   int CZ = correctAnswer.indexOf("CZ");
   int DZ = correctAnswer.indexOf("DZ");
   int ANZ = correctAnswer.indexOf("ANZ");          

   String choiceA = null;
   String choiceB = null;
   String choiceC = null;
   String choiceD = null;

   choiceA = correctAnswer.substring( (AZ+2), (BZ) );
   choiceB = correctAnswer.substring( (BZ+2), (CZ) );
   choiceC = correctAnswer.substring( (CZ+2), (DZ) );
   choiceD = correctAnswer.substring( (DZ+2), (ANZ) );
```

The logcat is as follows:

```
11-09 21:14:08.495: E/AndroidRuntime(25905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 21:14:08.495: E/AndroidRuntime(25905): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.trial.quizgame/com.trial.quizgame.QuizGame}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; regionStart=1; regionLength=-2
11-09 21:14:08.495: E/AndroidRuntime(25905):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
```

I have tried to set the buttons as .setText(correctAnswer) and it will correctly show as Number-Q01AZ7BZ8CZ9DZ10ANZ8, so the top part of getting the String for "correctAnswer" should be ok. The problem left at extracting strings, yet BZ must be at a position behind AZ, so as CZ behind BZ, etc:

From the logcat the regionLength is -2? How could I handle this?
I would like it to be for Q01, choice A=7, B=8, C=9, D=10 and ANZ=8

thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: You haven't shown enough code to see what the problem is (how is correctAnswer built?) but you have shown enough to see that you really should think of another design.  All of your answers in one string and you are trying to split them out?  You will help yourself a lot if you think about this again.

Comment: I'll double Simon's response here. There's no reason to worry about doing weird compression or tricks to handle strings on an Android app when it creates exceptions and faults due to the complexity.

Comment: For hell's sake, run your application in debug mode, place a breakpoint to the beginning of this code, and step through... That is the way you should solve such an issue. Printing values into an EditText, that is just so no-go... Try it, it is a cleaner and better feeling ;)

Comment: thanks for your comments. Actually I am also thinking of the design but I not yet think out of a better design (still learning). My thought here is that for every question (as an image), the answer is already included in the filename, and so the filename is designed in this way. Actually beforehand I have used Number-Q01_7_8_9_10_8.png which looks easier to read and substring by spliting "_", but again the same problems comes out, and would like to post here and seek for your professional advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption on the strings value is wrong. This code, if AZ, BZ, CZ, DZ, ANZ is present, should run with no error.

Either run debugger as advised in comments, or use android logcat to provide some debugging context. `android.utils.Log.d("APP", String.format("AZ=%d", AZ));`

How you store your data is not a big deal. You can tune it for days... You could create xml files that contain the name of the image, and the four possible answers... You can use the underscore approach, you can stay with your current one. Til it is only used by you, it doesn't really matter. You should just keep it simple. More complex => more chance for bugs...

So I'd advise reading about debugging and logging instead of refining the way you store the information... Storing it in the filename, that's a smart idea, quick and efficient, an ideal hack...

Comment: You first statement is false.  "SOMESTRINGAZ" wil fail, since `int AZ = correctAnswer.indexOf("AZ"+2, (BZ));`

Comment: I wrote that if AZ, BZ, CZ, DZ, ANZ is present in the String (in that particular order), then it should produce no error... Where is the problem with that?